# DOCplex adding columns

Tags: cplex, column-generation, docplex

When using DOCplex to implement column generation, is it possible to add columns as an object, as opposed to creating a variable and then modifying the coefficients in the constraints?

**Edit:** In gurobi one can add a column creating the object [Column](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_column2.html) and passing that object as the last argument of the [function that creates variables](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_addvar.html)

Comment: Since you tagged your question with [tag:column_generation], maybe [this link](http://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/cutstock.html) has something to help.

Comment: Is this really a question about column generation (which is an algorithmic technique) or just about whether the model itself can be built column-wise instead of row-wise?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 is about implementing column generation in docplex. The issue is that adding one variable at a time and changing the coefficients is very slow.

Comment: @EhsanK that was my first attempt. That example implements the approach I described (create a variable and then modify the coefficients in the constraints).

Comment: @DanielDuque OK, please check my edits to make sure they are OK.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 great thanks, that's it.

Answer (score 4):

let me a tiny example out of my [zoo and buses story](https://medium.com/@alexfleischer_84755/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6):

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

# original model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
ctKids=mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()



for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("Same number of 40 and 30 seats buses")

mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40==nbbus30, 'samenumberofbuses')

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)    


print()
print("Now with buses with 50 seats")




# And now we add 50 seats buses

nbbus50 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus50')

ctKids.left_expr.add_term(nbbus50, 50)
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400 + nbbus50*700)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

gives

```
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0

Same number of 40 and 30 seats buses
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0

Now with buses with 50 seats
nbBus40  =  3.0
nbBus30  =  3.0
nbBus50  =  2.0
```

Comment: This approach does the job, but I'm looking for something like the Column object in gurobi-python api. This is just for speed in implementation. See the last argument on this: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_addvar.html